# Include objects in a commit that are unchanged (Needed for external systems integrated with GIT that trigger on commit)

Tags: git, bitbucket

We have GIT (Bit Bucket) integrated with Jira.  As objects are modified - the commit message is used to attach the commit to the Jira story.  Then later on we build a package for named Jira stories.  This process looks at Jira and then its commit and extracts those code objects to build the final package.

If git commit has happened and then pushed - and later on we need to include it in a different story for any reason (reason not in scope of the discussion here), then there is no easy way to do this.

Currently we need to make an inconsequential change (like adding an empty line) to track it.

I have already tried

- Git commit --allow-empty.  That forced the commit but that commit did not have the files that I needed.

It looks like the issue starts with git add which does not recognize the file as changed and there does not seem to be a way to force it.  I tried touching the file - then git commit does not recognize the change.

The use case makes sense but I have not found any solution for this.  Changing the commit message in history for git is not simple if some time has passed and it is pushed.  And all I am interested in is to assign the commit to a different jira story.

Saad

Comment: A Git commit *does* include unchanged files: every commit is a full snapshot of every file that Git knows about. The problem you're running into happens when software *compares* an older snapshot to a newer one. Such software (rather reasonably) ignores the files that have not changed. So you must have some actual change for that software to not-ignore the (not-identical) pair of files (in old vs new commit). The solution you need is to improve Jira itself somehow; how that would happen is not clear.

Comment: Answer makes sense.  Looks like git is not the right tool if the intention is to take "pieces out of your repo irrespective of how/when they were committed".  The concepts of SVN, e.g., which considered each object (file) as having its own history is not how GIT views the world.  GIT views it as a single rep and likes a world where developers work on a change and merge it back to the main and build a unified deployment set all the time - makes sense.

In Git world, is it possible to arbitrarily define "meta-tags" for "files"? So I could say "this file is last [needed] by this Jira"?

Comment: Yes, a lot of older version control systems really work internally on files (and then maybe add a grouping mechanism atop that) but Git works differently. There's no easy way to attach anything to a file path name in Git. Git does have "git notes" (which lets you attach an editable note to a commit hash ID) but it does not extend this to tree or blob objects (if it did there might be a way to get what you're suggesting). I don't know how Atlassian actually implement Jira internally, but I'd bet it would be easier to do this directly in Jira, though.

Comment: They have not done any magic.  Commit message references the Jira story.It parses that string and puts a hyper link to that jira story where hyperlink is to actual commit.
So say I modified 3 files and during commit my commit message was "Jira-123 - modified these files for this reason", the commit hook communicates to Jira and will add to story "Jira-123" a hyper link to https://xxxx?jira_commit_number=blah.  
Now when I see Jira story Jira-123 I can directly go to that link and see what was changed.
And I "can" also create a package for those 3 files - but that is where the concept fails